# Stored Procedure to get next Progressive ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am not sure about which is the best practice to get an incremental ID in my application (rely on SQL Server to persist each counter).
In my scenario when the apllication need a new ID it call my stored procedure, that procedure guarant tha a new, incremental and unique ID is get.
That ID is not used as a key of any table, is used in business logic of application (much more like a token).

EG : I have read that Select with subsequent Update can cause dadlock (something about shared lock).
I would like to avoid it in my actual stored procedure :

```
declare @Current bigint, @Number bigint

BEGIN TRAN T1
    select @Current = [Counter] from dbo.NumberRange where [Item] = 'Customer'

    SET @Number =  @Current + 1 ;

    UPDATE [dbo].NumberRange
    SET [Counter] =  @Number
    WHERE [Item] = 'Customer'
COMMIT TRAN T1

RETURN @Number;
```

I missunderstood something ? is there the correctway to do it ?

Comment: Sequence/IDENTITY. There is no point of reinventing wheel.

Comment: @lad2025 can you refer to me an exemple on how request that ID throught stored procedure ?

Comment: Good starting point [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

Comment: Really interesting, thanks, is not in the scope of the question but SEQUENCE guarant to me also the coninuity of the sequence ? 
(i reapeat is not neede at the moment, but maybe in the future)

Comment: Your current solution's *only* guarantee is that you'll definitely have duplicates on a busy system ..... this approach is ***NOT*** safe - don't use it!

Comment: @marc_s why duplciates ? i never had ones, deadlock sometimes. In any case i agree SQUENCE seems a better solution.

Comment: Well, if your table has a value of `1000` , and two users call your function at the same time, both will get `1001` as their value back and use it. It **will** happen - I guarantee you! The `BEGIN TRAN` around your code does ***NOT*** protect you from this happening

Comment: @marc_s ah i supposed it apply a lock,in fact i can not query or altrer tble where are pending trnasactions.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: A transaction doesn't lock - it merely makes sure either all operations works, or get rolled back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `SEQUENCE`, it's designed exactly for this use case.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[MySequence]
  START WITH 0
  INCREMENT BY 1;

UPDATE [dbo].[NumberRange]
SET [Counter] = NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[MySequence]
WHERE [Item] = 'Customer';
```

Comment: Worth noting this method will only work in SQL Server 2012 and above.